# USACO site not accepting python solution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the ride problem on the USACO training portal. https://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=LKfegLjs7AJ&S=ride 
My solution is not passing even though I have tested it and it works.

I have tried looking at the directions for how to parse input.

```
'''
ID: krishpa2
LANG: PYTHON3
TASK: ride
'''

fin = open('ride.in','r')
fout = open('ride.out','w')
group = fin.readline().split()
comet = fin.readline().split()
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
group_tot,comet_tot = 1,1
for x,y in zip(group,comet):
    group_tot *= alpha.index(x)+1
    comet_tot *= alpha.index(y)+1
if group_tot % 47 == comet_tot % 47:
    fout.write("GO" + '\n')
    fout.close()
else:
    fout.write("STAY" + '\n')
    fout.close()
```

I should be able to pass all the tests.

Comment: The problem statement says, "This means that you fill in your header with:
`PROG: ride` WARNING: You must have 'ride' in this field or the wrong test data (or no test data) will be used." You have `TASK: ride` instead. Try changing that line to `PROG: ride`.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your solution to something like this (change the logic to yours, just this style of the boiler plate code should work):

```
"""
ID: krishpa
LANG: PYTHON3
TASK: ride
"""
def get_score(s):
    score = 1
    for c in s:
        score *= ord(c) - ord('A') + 1
    return score


def should_ride(comet, group):
    return get_score(comet) % 47 == get_score(group) % 47


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fin = open('ride.in', 'r')
    fout = open('ride.out', 'w')
    comet, group = fin.read().splitlines()
    result = "GO\n" if should_ride(comet, group) else "STAY\n"
    fout.write(result)
    fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers I made: (Python 2 and Python 3)

Python 2 solution:

```
"""
ID:krishpa2
LANG: PYTHON2
TASK: ride
"""
from functools import reduce
def char_to_num(c):
    return ord(c) - ord('A') + 1

def line_to_code(s):
    nums = list(map(char_to_num, s))
    code = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, nums) % 47
    return code

with open("ride.in", "r") as input_file:
    raw_lines = input_file.readlines()
lines = [s.strip() for s in raw_lines]
codes = list(map(line_to_code, lines))
should_go = codes[0] == codes[1]

with open("ride.out", "w") as output_file:
    if should_go: output_file.write("GO\n")
    else: output_file.write("STAY\n")
```

Python 3 solution:

```
"""
ID: krishpa2
LANG: PYTHON3
TASK: ride
"""
fin = open ('ride.in', 'r')
fout = open ('ride.out', 'w')
comet = fin.readline().lower().rstrip("\n")
cn = 1
group = fin.readline().lower().rstrip("\n")
gn = 1
res = ""
for a in range(len(comet)):
    cn = cn * (ord(comet[a]) - 96)
    #print(cn)
for b in range(len(group)):
    gn = gn * (ord(group[b]) - 96)
if cn%47 == gn%47:
    res = "GO"
else:
    res = "STAY"

fout.write (res + '\n')
fout.close()
```

P.S. I am also using the website and I have solved the ride problem already on the website. My ID is simu1

Comment: By the way, the Python 2 one is more pythonic than the Python 3 one, as I am kind of new to Python 3